# Python Regex search bad escaping

Tags: python, regex, django

This has been bugging me and I can't seem to find a fix. I have a function that has worked since I don't know when, that searches a binary file for a byte string...

```
foo = abin.read()
bar = re.search(b'\x03\NIBA', foo)
```

Since updating to win 10 and django 2.10 - I now get an error...

```
bad escape \N at position 1
```

I am missing encoding parameters or such? double escaping doesn't fix.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use re.search. There is no regex here.

Comment: You probably went from Python 2 to Python 3. Try using `re.search(r'\x03\\NIBA', foo)` and see if that passes your tests.

Comment: Daniel - I'm not an educated programmer, as you might guess - any pointing in the right direction? 9769953 - can't use rawstring on a bytes type object.

Comment: as far as I know, `\N` is not a valid escape sequence, hence why you get the error.. did you mean anything special by `\N`?

Comment: From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) "Changed in version 3.6: Unknown escapes consisting of '\' and an ASCII letter now are errors"

Comment: Sundeep - it's whats in the file as it appears. I got it to work searching for '\x03NIBA' - Daniel Roseman: why is this not regex? re is regex and I'm searching - it is also regex that throws an error.

Comment: How are you using `bar` ? If it is just to test for the presence, then a simple `foo.find(b'\x03\\NIBA') != -1` would work equally well.